# Python - Problema ao fazer o print dentro de um loop

Tags: python, loop, break

Eu tenho o seguinte codigo `Python`, representativo do jogo `Pedra,Papel,Tesoura`.

```
import random
listChoices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
print("Choose rock, paper or scissor to play or write exit to leave the game")
userChoice = str.lower(input("Rock,Paper or Scissor: "))

for choice in listChoices:
if userChoice != choice:
    print("You have to choose one of the this three options to play: rock, paper or scissor or exit to leave the game")
    break

pcChoice = random.choice(listChoices)

while userChoice != "exit":
if(userChoice == pcChoice):
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("It's a tie")
elif ((userChoice == "rock" and pcChoice == "scissor") or (userChoice == "scissor" and pcChoice == "paper") or (userChoice == "paper" and pcChoice == "rock") ):
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("User Wins congrats!!!!! :)")
elif ((pcChoice == "rock" and userChoice == "scissor") or (pcChoice == "scissor" and userChoice == "paper") or (pcChoice == "paper" and userChoice == "rock") ):
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("Pc Wins Try Again!!!!! :(")
break
```

O problema é o seguinte sempre que corro o programa e se o utilizador não escrever o que o programa pede (`rock,paper ou sciassor`) ele imprime a mensagem de erro e termina o programa. Por outro lado se ele imprimir uma dessas três opções para alem de executar o bloco que está dentro do `while`, imprime também a mensagem de erro anteriormente descrita.
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Eu também criei um jogo igual a esse, leia o meu código e tente entender o seu problema: https://repl.it/Fiza/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estavas a percorrer a lista das possiveis escolhas, e a comparar cada valor ('rock', 'paper', scissor) com o que o user colocou, ora sendo assim ele ia sempre parar em algum que o user não tivesse colocado. Assim é como acho que queres:

```
import random
listChoices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
print("Choose rock, paper or scissor to play or write exit to leave the game")

userChoice = str.lower(input("Rock,Paper or Scissor: "))
while userChoice not in listChoices:
    print("You have to choose one of the this three options to play: rock, paper or scissor or exit to leave the game")
    userChoice = str.lower(input("Rock,Paper or Scissor: "))

pcChoice = random.choice(listChoices)

if(userChoice == pcChoice):
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("It's a tie")
elif ((userChoice == "rock" and pcChoice == "scissor") or (userChoice == "scissor" and pcChoice == "paper") or (userChoice == "paper" and pcChoice == "rock") ):
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("User Wins congrats!!!!! :)")
else:
    print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
    print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
    print("Pc Wins Try Again!!!!! :(")
```

E aqui tens uma maneira de ficar a repetir até o user colocar "exit":

```
import random

listChoices = ["rock","paper","scissor"]
print("Choose rock, paper or scissor to play or write exit to leave the game")

userChoice = str.lower(input("Rock,Paper or Scissor: "))
while True:
    while userChoice not in listChoices:
        if userChoice == 'exit':
            break
        print("You have to choose one of the this three options to play: rock, paper or scissor or exit to leave the game")
        userChoice = str.lower(input("Rock,Paper or Scissor: "))

    else: # isto acontece se nao tiver havido break em cima
        pcChoice = random.choice(listChoices)

        if(userChoice == pcChoice):
            print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
            print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
            print("It's a tie")
        elif ((userChoice == "rock" and pcChoice == "scissor") or (userChoice == "scissor" and pcChoice == "paper") or (userChoice == "paper" and pcChoice == "rock") ):
            print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
            print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
            print("User Wins congrats!!!!! :)")
        else:
            print("User Choice --> ",(userChoice))
            print("Pc Choice --> ",(pcChoice))
            print("Pc Wins Try Again!!!!! :(")

        userChoice = None
        continue
    break
```